# Couldn't get values of textbox from footer row of gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, vb.net-2010

Actually my problem is i want to insert new row in a footer row of gridview while clicking the button which is outside of the gridview,i couldn't get the values of text box in the footer row of gridview

my coding is

```
Dim footerRow As GridViewRow = grvTBD_LoanProducts.FooterRow
Dim sStateCode As String = TryCast(footerRow.FindControl("txtStateCode"), TextBox).Text
Dim sEntryTypeID As String = TryCast(footerRow.FindControl("txtEntryTypeID"),TextBox).Text
```

the above coding didn't works help me to fix it thanks in advance

Comment: What it means "it didn't work"? Please be more specific about your problem and add the error log, if it's giving any error.

Comment: variable sStateCode is "" it doesn't contain the value which i entered in txtstatecode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This code it might work:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    Dim txtName As TextBox = TryCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtStateCode"), TextBox)
    Dim aa As String = txtName.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: but i want this code in click_Event of button which is outside of the gridview. Will it works?

Comment: try this two lines inside button click :- Dim txtName As TextBox = TryCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtStateCode"), TextBox)
    Dim aa As String = txtName.Text

Comment: Can you try this one :- Dim sStateCode As String =  GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[0].Text

Comment: But Thank U For Ur valuable Time :)

Comment: Finally Found the solution i have given the loaddata() outside the Not IsPostBack method in the Page_Load. Now its working fine thank u Arul Dinesh For your Reply

Comment: @user2915027 If this answer is usefull for you select the tick mark.